# How to find whether system is using systemd and glib specific version in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I am trying to identify system using systemd and glibc version 2.17 and then run specific set of code. This is what I have come out with but i get error

```
 ./testing.sh: line 4: [[UNIT: command not found
```

CODE:

```
#!/bin/sh
glib=`ldd --version | awk '/ldd/{print $NF}'`
ver=2.17
if [[`systemctl`=~-\.mount && $glib '==' $ver ]];then
echo "I have to execute certain specific stuff to glib ver 2.17"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use the two `[[ ]]` test form, this is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (or ksh), so :

```
#!/bin/bash

glib=$(ldd --version | awk '/ldd/{print $NF}')

if [[ $glib == 2.17 ]] && systemctl | grep -q '\.mount'; then
  echo "I have to execute certain specific stuff to glib ver 2.17"
fi
```

#### NOTE

- use `$( )` not `` in modern shell
- place spaces around `[[` and `]]`
- your regex try is better written with a [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)